# NGINX is unable to connect to the Docker container running the Nest.js server on an EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, cors

I have been trying to figure it out for more than two weeks now but nothing seems to help.

I'm have two EC2 instances:

Instance 1: Hosts Docker containers for the server, Nginx, and the database.
Instance 2: Runs a React-based client-side application.

In my NGINX conf file I have configured the CORS policy and it seems to be working, as in, upon inspection of the NGINX container logs, the preflight request is successful, but the client is still logging this error to the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.<DOMAIN-NAME>/user/get' from origin 'https://<DOMAIN-NAME>.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The main problem is that when the NGINX is trying to reach the server it returns a connection refused (111) error and a Bad Gateway (502) error:

```
GET /user/get HTTP/2.0" 502 559 "https://<domain-name>.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023/12/01 12:43:00 
[error] 29#29: *34 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 162.158.103.162, server: api.<domain-name>.com, 
request: "GET /user/get HTTP/2.0", 
upstream: "http://<container-port>:8080/user/get", 
host: "api.<domain-name>.com", 
referrer: "https://<domain-name>.com/"
```

My nest js server container is running and not crashing, upon inspeciton it is returning these logs:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from src/database/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "db", schema "public" at "database:5432"
...
[Nest] Nest application successfully started ...
```

So it starts and runs successfully.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: <user>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <password>
      POSTGRES_DB: <db>
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - <network>

  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - <network>
    depends_on:
      - <db>
    command: sh -c "while ! nc -z <db> 5432; do sleep 1; done && npx prisma db push && npm run start:prod"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./certbot/conf:/var/cert
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - <network>

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw

networks:
  network:

volumes:
  data:
```

My `Dockerfile` just loads the nginx image, copies prisma schemas and builds the dist folder as well as starts the server:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

COPY ./src/database/schema.prisma ./prisma/ 

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

My `nginx.conf` sets up letsencrypt and redirects users that reach an http endpoint to https, acts as a reverse proxy and passes requests to the server container, configures CORS:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name api.<domain-name>.com;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
        return 301 https://api.<domain-name>.com$request_uri;
        }
    }


    server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        http2 on;

        server_name api.<domain-name>.com;

        ssl_certificate /var/cert/live/api.<domain-name>.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/cert/live/api.<domain-name>.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://<domain-name>.com' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';             
           add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;

           if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://<domain-name>.com';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';

                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
           }

           if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://<domain-name>.com' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';             
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }

           if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://<domain-name>.com' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';               
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }

            proxy_pass http://<docker-container-name>:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Since CORS is already configured in CORS I am not configuring it in on my server as well.
My client application is also setup with HTTPS.

My firewall policy on the EC2 instance is set up to allow SSH at port 22 at my IP adress, allow HTTP and HTTPS at 80 and 443 at all adresses, allow TCP at 8080, 5433 at my private EC2 instance IP adress.

Despite all the efforts I have yet to figure out what is causing the issue, could someone please provide insights into what could be going on with this setup?

Comment: Can you fill in the host name in both the error message and the Nginx `proxy_pass` line?  (I'd expect both places to be the name `server` from the Compose file.)  If you run the Compose file locally, can you make a `curl` request to the proxy and get back an HTTP 200 response?

Comment: Thanks, I checked it locally and instead of getting an error on a curl request to the server container the request just hanged and when trying to connect normally through port 80 on the NGINX container the request was returning 502, I figured there could be something wrong with how the server was set up in nest and found out that while troubleshooting other issues I edited the app.listen(8080) line in main.ts to app.listen(8080, 'localhost'). Was advised to do it by chatgpt and forgot to get rid of it after it didnt work. Now the server is running normally and getting no CORS errors